# JSP Table with multiple ArrayLists/linkedHashmaps

Tags: foreach, html-table, hashmap, jstl

I'm not sure if I'm approaching this right, but here's what I want to do. Print a LinkedHashMap and an ArrayList (and eventually more of these) into a table in a JSP page. So far, they both have the same length. I am able to get their values (e.g. people's first/last names) into table rows from a LinkedHashMap. I can get ArrayList values too.. Now, how do I get both? Do I have to make a separate object/class for them? Or put ArrayLists inside a LinkedHashMap? It seems like more work when data will originally come from a database. Is there certain JSTL syntax to iterate a table's creation using both? Something like:

```
<c:forEach items="${pNames}" var="current" >
```

But have multiple items? Is there a better design approach to this, because I don't want to over-complicate.

By the way, here's basically a table minus the header and without an additional ArrayList

```
<c:forEach items="${pNames}" var="current" >
<tr><td>${current.value}, ${current.key}</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might be over complicating the matter. If this data is all coming from a database, why are you using multiple data structures?

I think it depends on how your data is fetched as well. If you are using JPA entities, you can simply create a list of entity objects and generate your tables on the fly using them. For instance if I have a Person table and a corresponding person entity with getters and setters for first/last name, email, phone, etc ... I would create a List of people objects and then in my JSP page use JSTL to iterate through them:

```
<c:forEach items="${people}" var="person" >

    <tr>
        <td>${person.lastName}, ${person.firstName}</td>
    </tr>

</c:forEach>
```